# Draw Plot (tikzpicture) from csv file in TEX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

I am having troubles using csv files to create plot similar to png file.

There are two csv files which includes results of two different models (Kobert, XLM-R).

I want to make plot in latex looks same as png file with above two csv files. I hope I can get help from you.

[image: PNG examples]

[image: CSV file of KoBERT]

[image: CSV file XLM-R]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Is the formatting built into the csv, because the first thing you need is a plain text file, possibly comma de;limited.

Comment: @Choii, Is your question answered?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[margin=-2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=step, y=value, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Make sure that you have `data.csv` in your project.